# Cannot fetch api due to array react native

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

I bulid an api using laravel which can run in postman (http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications). The problem is when i fetch using an example from this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuYo009yc8w&t=430s) where there is a array in the api then i have to setstate the array which is working well but when i try using the below code it does not render due to it is not using array in the api for example the random user api have "results" :[item], and mine one is "data":[my item]

```
  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api?results=500");
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: json.results });
  };
```

if i use this will work but i want to use below code due to some homework i am doing

```
type Props = {};
export default class IndexScreen extends Component<Props> {
...
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isFetching: false,
    };

    _load() {
    let url = "http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications";

    this.setState({isFetching: true});

    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      if(!response.ok) {
        Alert.alert('Error', response.status.toString());
        throw Error('Error ' + response.status);
      }

      return response.json()
    })
    .then((members) => {
      this.setState({data});
      this.setState({isFetching: false});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mPB2.jpg this is my render
the result i get the code i run is blank is loading

Comment: can you `console.log` the result and add it to your question

Comment: which data you mean when you call this.setState({ data })

Comment: The 1st method work but when i use the 2nd it does,t show my data what i am saying is should i add json.data to my this.setstat(data: json.data) since my api is in data object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fetch request is working but you are not saving the right data in the right state property.

The issues is located in the following part:

```js
.then((members) => {
    this.setState({data});
    this.setState({isFetching: false});
})
```

You are assigning the response to a variable `members` but saving another variable `data`, which does not exist.

In addition, the response is an object with more information than just the data, so what you are looking for is just the `data` property of the response.

This should work:

```js
.then(({ data }) => {
    this.setState({data});
    this.setState({isFetching: false});
})
```

Here we destructure the response into the variable `{ data }`, solving your issue.

Comment: should't be my members is the array

Comment: Here `data` is your array of members

Comment: nvm work now i just delete and react- native run andorid again

Comment: Replace `this.state.members` by `this.state.data` in your FlatList

Answer (score 0):

Based on the snippets you don't use the fetched data to set it to your state:

```
    .then((members) => {
      this.setState({data});
      this.setState({isFetching: false});
    })
```

`members`is the result of your fetched json. So either rename `members` to `data` or use `data: members`. If the code should work like your first function it's probably `data: members.result`. You can also combine the two `setState` calls to one single call:

```
      this.setState({
           data: members.result,
           isFetching: false,
      });
```